# How do I boot a desktop environment from the command line with no display manager or wifi?

Tags: fedora, login, display-manager

KDE was my DM and I remove KDE and XFCE in turn for LXDE (which I had installed.) When I boot, I boot into the command line and have to login with no GUI. The "startx" command boots me into KDE, even though I know I have LXDE installed too. I don't know why there is no GUI login, maybe the KDE removal process got interrupted, but I boot to command line. I don't know how to get wifi through command line.

Fedora 20 on a x86_64 processor.

Answer (score 1):

Add `exec startlxde` to `~/.xinitrc` and run `startx`

Reference:  [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Console)